# Hyphen missing with reading in text file

Tags: python, character-encoding

I try to read text file with these code

```
Text_file = open("file.txt", 'r', encoding="UTF-8", errors='ignore') 
firstLine = Text_file.readline()
print(firstLine)

output : search leschnyhan syndrome
```

but original text is like this

```
search lesch–nyhan syndrome
```

So how can i do to read text file with hyphen. thank you

Comment: What happens if you remove `errors='ignore'`?

Comment: Works for me man, don't know what to tell you.

Comment: Just which console is the output going to? There are many consoles that can use Python and some of those cannot handle characters outside the standard ASCII or ANSI set. That hyphen may not be the ASCII hyphen--there are multiple characters in Unicode that look like a hyphen. Use a hex editor on your file to see the exact representation of that "hyphen" in your file.

Comment: @snakecharmerb The output will be like this `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 55: invalid start byte`

Comment: @Rory Daulton I try it on visual studio code terminal, and it not showing hyphen, so i will try with another one.

Comment: It works fine in my Visual Studio Code terminal. What is your operating system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments:

> The output will be like this `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 55: invalid start byte`

This tells us that the file is not encoded as UTF-8; because it is being opened with `errors='ignore'`, the offending character is ignored, and so doesn't appear in the output.

The way to fix this is to determine the correct encoding and use that encoding to open the file.  You could use a tool like [chardet](https://pypi.org/project/chardet/) to find the likely encoding, or guess.  For example cp1252 is a common encoding on Windows machines, and happens to encode an en-dash as `b'\x96'`.

Answer (score 3):

When I copy-and-paste your line `search lesch–nyhan syndrome` into Notepad then save it and examine it with a hex editor, I see that the "hyphen" is not actually a hyphen. The bytes in the file are

```
E2 80 93
```

When unencoded that yields the Unicode character with the decimal code `8211` and is [the en-dash](https://www.codetable.net/decimal/8211).

There are many consoles that can use Python and some of those cannot handle characters outside the standard ASCII or ANSI set. It appears that your console cannot handle that character. Try another console like those in Sypder or Visual Studio Code.

To be sure, try executing `print ord(firstLine[12:13])` and see if you get the result `8211`. If so, you are getting the character out of the file and into your character but not into your console.

Comment: It's also possible that the file is not encoded as UTF-8. For example encoding an en-dash as cp1252 and decoding as UTF-8 would raise an exception, were the `errors='ignore'` option not set.

Comment: @snakecharmerb: When I copy-and-pasted the line into Notepad there was no problem. My further investigations in Visual Studio Code also worked well. So if the OP copy-and-pasted into the Stack Overflow editor, the text itself and its encoding seem to be fine.

Comment: i tried print ord(firstLine[13:14]) on vs code terminal and the result is `115`, so what is that mean.

Comment: @Kaow: My wife interrupted me (a common excuse, I know, but true in this case) so  I got the indices wrong. Try `print ord(firstLine[12:13])`. (I corrected that just before you did your comment.) I get `8211` for that.